# How could I copy the functioning of "ls | wc -l < myinputfile.txt" at bash in C?

Tags: c, bash, file, process, pipe

I'm working on a C minishell project, I'm making `|` and `<` which copy the behavior of a pipe and an input redirection. The problem is I don't know how could I copy the behavior of this input in bash:

```sh
ls | wc -l < myinputfile.txt
```

Because what it does in bash is to prompt the sum of lines which outputs the first process (ls) and the lines of the **myinputfile.txt ** so firstly `ls | wc -l` is `10` and `wc -l < myinputfile.txt` is `15`, so the output should be `25`.

For the pipes `|` I use the `pipe()` function in C and execute both processes each in a child process with `fork()`, and if it detects a `<` I change the `stdin` with `dup2(myinputfile, 0)` so in the previous example my output would be `15` and not the sum of both. For execution of the process I need to use `execve` so each child process finishes instantly after the execution of the command (if there is no error). How could I prompt the output of the sum of both as in bash in a simple way?

Comment: `the sum of lines` No, it wil not output the sum, it will only output the count of lines from the file. Output from `ls` will be completely ignored. Note that you tagged Bash _not_ zsh or fish. `How could I prompt the output of the sum` You have to spawn yet another process, that reads from `ls`, and then reads from the file, and the output from that process goes to `wc`. This is _not_ the behavior of Bash. In Bash you would `ls | cat - myinputfile.txt | wc -l` - which is exactly what you _want_ to implement, a separate process in between.

Comment: `ls | wc -l < myinputfile.txt` isn't something you'd normally write, since the output of `ls` is effectively discarded.  Some shells give an error, saying it's an ambiguous redirect, but bash silently allows it.  In effect, it's essentially the same as `ls > /dev/null; wc -l < myinputfile.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the behavior of `ls | wc -l < myinputfile.txt` is not what you explain: the shell opens the file **myinputfile.txt** for input and redirects the input file to the `wc -l` command, replacing the pipe read side that was set up for `|` which gets closed.

On one hand, `ls` outputs to the pipe (via `printf()`, calling `write()`), which is closed on the read side, so it gets a `SIGPIPE` signal and dies or if it catches this signal, the `write` syscall fails with an `EPIPE` error, causing the writing process to either exit or continue depending on its error handling at this point.

On the other, `wc -l` reads the contents of the file and outputs the number of lines read.

No implicit concatenation occurs.

Conversely, if you write `ls & wc -l < myinputfile.txt`, the output of both `ls` and `wc -l < myinputfile.txt` get mixed in an unpredictable fashion to the current shell output.

To get concatenated output, you could write `ls && wc -l < myinputfile.txt`, the output of both `ls` and `wc -l < myinputfile.txt` get concatenated, assuming `ls` exits with a `0` status.

Comment: @chqrlie I think there's a fork for `wc -l`, and that fork opens `myinputfile.txt` for standard input, ignoring the pipe that was open at the time of the fork.  With nothing reading from the pipe, you might get an error if the output from `ls` was long enough.

Comment: I think it's closed when the file is opened, since both use the same file descriptior (i.e. 0).  The pipe is unread, so you get an error if the buffer fills up.

Comment: @TomKarzes: I think I got it right time time: `ls` is killed by the `SIGPIPE` signal when attempting to write to the pipe. The behavior of `cat | wc -l < myinputfile.txt`  is consistent with this: `wc` outputs the number of lines as `cat` is waiting for input and `cat` dies without output as soon as input is provided (`stdin` is line buffered for the `cat` process so a single line suffices).

Comment: I guess what's confusing me is when you get a "broken pipe" error vs. when the writing process just silently exits.  I guess it depends on how the process handles a SIGPIPE signal when writing to a pipe.

Comment: @TomKarzes I think your guess is right. A small test program with `int main(){raise(SIGPIPE);}` dies silently (as opposed to what it does if you, e.g., raise `SIGTERM` instead). I suspect that when you see "Broken pipe", it's because the program caught the signal and called `perror` or something on `write`'s failure.